# How can I tell if a macro is being run from an email or desktop with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, email, desktop

I've developed macros for a number of years.  We users run these macros from a local drive.  However, due to turnover, new hires, etc., this info isn't always passed on to new users.

We have a central location where users download copies of these macros.  If they follow procedures, it saves the macro to a local drive.  However, sometimes users get macros from co-workers via email.  Then they open from the email or save them to their desktop.

If they run our macros from either an email or a desktop, there can be issues; which often requires someone to contact us for support.  I'd like to try and cut down the number of support calls.

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell if the macro was opened from an email or from the user's desktop.  Ideally, I'm thinking of adding code to an "On Open" module and displaying a message that would tell the user to save the macro to a local drive before opening / running it.

However, I'm not sure how to identify these 2 locations.  I've used the "Path" property before but these macros could be on any number of drives across hundreds of field offices.  I thought it would be better if I could identify an email or a desktop location and then display the message.

Most of our users are on Office 2010 or 2016.  Thanks for the help..........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the workbook from the mail and debug `ThisWorkbook.Path` you will get something like:

`? thisworkbook.Path
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.Outlook\9PWSZZ9J`

The same thing will go to the desktop, so you can use the `Workbook_Open()` trigger to check the workbook path, if it is like *Outlook* or *Desktop* send a message warning to save it on the local drive.

Edited due to Shaves comments:

There is a final approach. Let's just say that their group policy let them save files on the local Dirve C: (supposing they all got that drive)

Your approach could be,

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim DesiredFilePath As String, CurrentFilePath As String, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    DesiredFilePath = "C:\" & wb.Name
    CurrentFilePath = wb.Path & "\" & wb.Name

    If DesiredFilePath <> CurrentFilePath Then
        wb.SaveAs DesiredFilePath
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill CurrentFilePath
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The file wasn't saved where it should be to work properly. It's been saved in: " & CurrentFilePath
    End If


End Sub
```

this way you don't just warn the user, you save the file where you need it to be and delete it from where it was warning the user how to find it.

Comment: @Damian..............Thank you very much.  I'm going to look at this today and start implementing it.  This should help a lot.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: A different approach could be checking if its not on the path you want it to be, i.e. `If ThisWorkbook.Path <> "C:\whereveryouneed" Then` and so

Comment: ++ Good suggestion :)

Comment: @Damian....Thanks for the help.  I used the 1st suggestion and it worked just like I expected it to.  The 2nd section wasn't as helpful for me because I wouldn't know all of the drive names.  There is a recommended drive but our users keep these macros in all sorts of locations.  I'm trying to reduce the number of calls we get from users that are trying to run these from an email or from their desktop.  This was a big win.  I sent it out to a couple of people for their input and am waiting to hear back from them.  Thanks again for your help...

Comment: @SiddharthRout.....Thanks for your suggestion as well.  It's a little more advanced than I am at this point but I certainly understand what you are showing.  Thanks again for your help.....

Comment: @Shaves `...because I wouldn't know all of the drive names....` Exactly. Nor would you know the MS Outlook (Not MS Office) version the user has and hence you should get those paths dynamically :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout wouldn't always that folder have the keyword "Outlook" on it? That should make my approach rather simple but effective. Yours is more advanced, but a bit of overkill right? shaves I've edited my post on your concerning about the drive.

Comment: `@SiddharthRout wouldn't always that folder have the keyword "Outlook" on it? That should make my approach rather simple but effective.` Yes but that will give you `False Positives`. So "Simple but effective"? Nope I don't think so... User can create a folder called `"C:\Temp\Outlook"` Overkill? Definitely not... BTW I am not asking anyone to do what I suggested.. I posted the "right way" to go about it. To use it or not to use it totally up to the user :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expanded version of what Damian suggested. I will divide it in 2 parts.

---

**PART ONE: FROM OUTLOOK**

I am demostrating with one MS Office version. Feel free to add more to the `Select Case`

When you open attachments from the email message before saving to the hard drive, Outlook places copies in the `SecureTemp` folder. This folder is a **hidden** folder under **Temporary Internet files**.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ol_Version As String
    Dim ol_RegKey As String
    Dim ol_SecureTempRegKey As String
    Dim ol_SecureTempFolder As String

    '~~> This is the registry key which stores Outlook's version
    ol_RegKey = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Outlook.Application\CurVer\"

    ol_Version = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead(ol_RegKey)

    '~~> Check the outlook version
    Select Case ol_Version
        Case "Outlook.Application.15"

            ol_SecureTempRegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Security\OutlookSecureTempFolder"
        '
        '~~> Add more cases here
        '
    End Select

    If ol_SecureTempRegKey <> "" Then
        ol_SecureTempFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead(ol_SecureTempRegKey)

        Debug.Print "Outlook's temp folder is " & ol_SecureTempFolder
    End If
End Sub
```

Once you get the `SecureTemp` path, you can check if the file was opened from Outlook.

---

**PART TWO: FROM DESKTOP**

To get the user's desktop folder path you can use this. Once you get the `Desktop` path, you can check if the file was opened from there.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim desktopPath As String

    desktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

    Debug.Print "User's desktop folder is " & desktopPath
End Sub
```